# Is there a syntactically correct way to replace text with an icon in CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

My code looks like

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li>link 1 </li>
  <li>link 2 </li>
  <li>link 3 </li>
  <li>link 4 </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

I am wondering if there is a way that I can hide the text `link #` on small devices (using media queries) and replace it with an icon (i.e. icons that will not be there when the page is full screen).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*play with the fiddle link to see it in action*

**HTML**

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><span class="text">link 1 </span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot icon"></span></li>
  <li><span class="text">link 2 </span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot icon"></span></li>
  <li><span class="text">link 3 </span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot icon"></span></li>
  <li><span class="text">link 4 </span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot icon"></span></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
    .icon{
        display : none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
     /* 500px is random value, adjust it as per your need */
    .icon{
        display : block;
    }
    .text{
        display:none;
    }
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/MBNNZ/1/)
twitter bootstrap icons are used just to demonstrate

Comment: THIS! This use of span tags is not considered bad practice or anything?

Comment: The span element is used as a generic inline container.There is nothing wrong with using span.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <nav>
   <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
         <span class="mobile-removed">link 1</span>
         <span class="mobile-added">Icon Code Here</span>
       </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Your main CSS file should display:none the mobile-added class, and your mobile CSS should display:none the mobile-removed class.

It might not be the best way, but it will work.